# Android Retrofit 2 post request responses with name of response class

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

In my app I make post request to the server with a special code inside the body. Then I should get some information in the response. However, I always get the name of the response class.

My request code:

```
@POST("/accounts/login/vk-oauth2/")
Call<RegistrationProcessCodeResponse> postCode(@Body CodePostRequest code);
```

My ResponseClass:

```
public class RegistrationProcessCodeResponse {
    private String message;
    private String partial_token;
    private String phase;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getPartial_token() {
        return partial_token;
    }

    public String getPhase() {
        return phase;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setPartial_token(String partial_token) {
        this.partial_token = partial_token;
    }

    public void setPhase(String phase) {
        this.phase = phase;
    }
}
```

My request code:

```
HseAlumniApi hseAlumniApi = HseAlumniApi.retrofit.create(HseAlumniApi.class);
Call<RegistrationProcessCodeResponse> postComment = hseAlumniApi.postCode(codePostRequest);
postComment.enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationProcessCodeResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationProcessCodeResponse> call, Response<RegistrationProcessCodeResponse> response) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "String.valueOf(response.code())\n" + String.valueOf(response.code()));
        Log.d("myLogs", "response.body().toString()\n" + response.body().toString());
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
           Log.d("myLogs", "Request succeeded");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationProcessCodeResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "Request failed");
    }
});
```

My logs:

```
D/myLogs: String.valueOf(response.code())
          200
D/myLogs: response.body().toString()
        com.example.vitaly.hsealumni.RegistrationProcessCodeResponse@498e7e7
D/myLogs: Request succeeded
```

Response Json:

```
{
"message": "email needed",
"partial_token": "231445d4fc5a4ed99dccb681942d5d7e",
"phase": 1
}
```

I really have no idea what to do, help please

Answer (score 3):

```
public class RegistrationProcessCodeResponse {
    private String message;
    private String partial_token;
    private String phase;

    public RegistrationProcessCodeResponse() {
        message = "";
        partial_token = "";
        phase = "";
    }

   // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RegistrationProcessCodeResponse{" +
            "message='" + message + '\'' +
            ", partial_token='" + partial_token + '\'' +
            ", phase='" + phase + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, all the fields are null in this case

Comment: @KalenikVitaly Yes, because you don't initialize them. You can provide an empty constructor and init them there.

Comment: You mean like this?
`public RegistrationProcessCodeResponse(){
        message = "";
        partial_token = "";
        phase = "";
    }`

Comment: Now the fields are just empty

Comment: I think you have wrong server kesy responses for `message`, `token` and `phase`. Response is not deserializated for your values names. Use `Gson`. Check api documentation.